# Angular 2 (Ionic 2): can't "render" Component inside Page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular2-template

I built an Angular 2 Component:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sidemenu'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/menu/menu.html',
})
export class Menu {
}
```

in a Page component, I can't use it in the template:

```
import {Menu} from '../menu/menu';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/content/content.html'
})
export class PO {

}
```

content.html:

```
<ion-content>
<sidemenu></sidemenu>
</ion-content>
```

isn't replaced by the Menu component's "html" (build/pages/menu/menu.html). But if I use dynamicComponentLoader to load the component inside an element from the DOM, it works (I did this to check if the component is ok).
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

directives: [Menu]

```
import {Menu} from '../menu/menu';
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/content/content.html',
directives: [Menu]
})
export class PO {

}
```

Comment: I tried this, now I get this error: "EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" if I try to use <sidemenu></sidemenu> inside the content.html

Comment: Try importing IONIC_DIRECTIVES in the directive as well

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Ionic but usually in Angular2 you need to list components you use in the template in the `@Component({ ..., directives: [Menu], ...}){ ...}`